# How do I extract specific elements from an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, subset

If I have an array `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and I want a subset of this array - the 1st, 5th and 7th elements. Is it possible to extract these from this array in a simple way. I was thinking something like:

```
a[0,4,6] = [1,5,7]
```

but that doesn't work.

Also is there a way to return all indices except those specified? For example, something like

```
a[-0,-4,-6] = [2,3,4,6,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
[0,4,6].map{|i| a[i]}
```

Answer (score 22):

You can simply do:

```
[1] pry(main)> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].values_at(0, 4, 6)
=> [1, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

For a[0,4,6] = [1,5,7] :

```
a.values_at(0, 4, 6)
=> [1, 5, 7]
```

For a[-0,-4,-6] = [2,3,4,6,8,9,10] :

```
a - a.values_at(0, 4, 6)
=> [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, Array objects have a method/operator `[]` which allows you to get/reference an object at a specific index, or a contiguous subset of objects specified by a range.

```
ary[index] → obj or nil
ary[start, length] → new_ary or nil
ary[range] → new_ary or nil
```

Personally, I like your syntax.  It would be useful but it is not provided by the standard Array object.  Until Ruby adopts your syntax, as others have suggested, you have the `values_at` method to do exactly what you need.

```
values_at(selector,... ) → new_ary
```

If `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, then:

```
a.values_at(0, 4, 6)
=> [1, 5, 7]
```